# How do I keep application deployed on EC2 Server for long?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have an spring boot application which is deployed on EC2 server which runs fine.

But after a certain amount of time, that task is killed automatically. I have tried to search for a solution but couldn't find any or may be I didn't exactly know what to search for. And hence the question on SO.

Is there anything that I can implement which will keep on pinging the instance which will keep it alive?
If yes, how do I implement it? And do I have to consider any other drawback for doing this?

Comment: is your java process is getting killed ? and if yes, did you check the logs why its getting killed ?

Comment: Yes, the java process gets killed. Nothing specific in logs..

Comment: can you start the java process using the nohup ?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I debugged the issue further and found that once my ssh connection deactivates, the java process gets killed. So, as per ur suggestion I looked into nohup and it looks feasible to me. But is this good enough to use for production application?

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1. Elastic Container Service**

Dockerize your app. Create a ECS cluster and publish you service. You Docker container will still run on a EC2 instance, but ECS will automatically maintain the number of app instances "alive". If you container gets killed (because the main Java process got killed), ECS will automatically restart the container.

**Option 2. Elastic Beanstalk**

Publish your Java app with Elastic Beanstalk and it will automatically monitor the "health" of you web app, and replace "unhealthy" EC2 instances automatically. It only works for web apps, since Elastic Beanstalk does HTTP(S) checks calling a URL you specify.

**Option 3. Use Elastic Load Balancer with Auto Scaling Group**

ELB can do HTTP(s) checks on you app. If an instance doesn't respond, it will be automatically replaced. You will require to create an AMI or cloud-init script to bootstrap new instances.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the details. Which one is the ideal solution if the web application usage will be pretty restricted. Only a handful of users?

Comment: Doesn't matter, these are all good options. If you're new to AWS, Beanstalk will probably be the easiest for you, since it will do a lot of orchestration automatically for you. And you can deploy both Docker and Java applications with Beanstalk.